# Is there any way to recover from somebody changing Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty?

Tags: javascript, prototype, hasownproperty

You always read that for-in loops should check `o.hasOwnProperty(k)` to skip over Object.prototype. Well, if somebody is stupid enough to modify Object.prototype, who's to say they won't do anything that conflicts with the existing prototype? For example, what if somebody runs this:

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty = function () {
    return !!'I am stupid';
};
```

**If this is the first script run**, does this mean that, for every script on the rest of the page, it is actually impossible to safely iterate over an object?

Comment: fun fact: I was playing around trying to solve this in the console of the ask question page, and, surprise surprise, when I tried to submit it the page was broken.

Comment: You'd have to be 10 times as *stupid* to overwrite `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` than you would to create a new property on the prototype.

Comment: @JuanMendes I agree - this is mostly a theoretical question.

Comment: Better title: `How can I recreate hasOwnProperty out of messed up prototype?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a temporary IFRAME element, and retrieve the method from its `Object.prototype` object:

```
(function () {
    var frame = document.createElement( 'iframe' );
    frame.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild( frame );
    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty = frame.contentWindow.Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
    document.body.removeChild( frame );
}());
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ARycC/2/

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you. Little note - `frame.contentWindow.Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` can be replaced with `frame.contentWindow.hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: @st-boost That won't work in IE8... (since in IE8 and before, `window` is not an instance of `Object`)

Comment: I didn't know that. Would `frame.contentDocument.hasOwnProperty` work?

Comment: @st-boost Nope. IE, before version 9, was just a different animal. None of the "host objects" were instances of `Object`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. One more try though: what about `frame.contentWindow.Object.hasOwnProperty`? That's got to work. (I should probably just install WINE...)

Comment: In case anybody else has the same question: yes, it does work. I just downloaded virtualbox etc to check.

Comment: @st-boost Yup, that one works. I wouldn't write it like that, though, since it misleads people into thinking that the `hasOwnProperty` method is defined on `Object` itself. And since `Object` *does* have own (so-called static) methods (like `Object.keys`, and `Object.create`), it's best to avoid any confusion and explicitly write `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`.

Answer (score 2):

```
function secret(){
    var HOP = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
    this.getHOP = function(){
        return HOP;
    }
}

new secret().getHOP(); //Will now be the copy of hasOwnProperty
                       //and nobody can modify it


//stupid script:
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty = function () {
    return !!'I am stupid';
};

//restore
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty = new secret().getHOP();  //DONE.
```

---

### UPDATE

<s>If it is modified before every script is loaded, then you can do this:</s>

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty = String.prototype.hasOwnProperty
```

<s>They are the same. `:D` And there are *whole lot more* for you to copy from:</s>

- `Boolean.prototype.hasOwnProperty`
- `Number.prototype.hasOwnProperty`
- `Function.prototype.hasOwnProperty`
- etc...

---

### UPDATE 2

New way to get the original function back:

```
var win=window.open("about:blank");
win.close();
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty = win.Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
```

Kind of hacky. Or you can create a hidden `<iframe>`.

```
var win = document.createElement("iframe");
win.style.display = "none";
document.body.appendChild(win);
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty = win.contentWindow.Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
document.body.removeChild(win);
```

Comment: See the comments on JuanMendes' answer - this is a nice solution for environments that we control, but still doesn't answer the question, which is how to recover if the problem script is run before all of our code.

Comment: `String` inherits from `Object` like everything else - `String.prototype.hasOwnProperty` is only a reference to `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: Okay... So that means there is no way you can revert it.

Comment: `private` is a reserved keyword, this (like my answers) still requires placing the code that stores the original HOP above code that could potentially modify it

Comment: @st-boost - Update #2 can get the original function back, but only with a flash of the new page created.

Comment: @derek Nice solution, make it less obtrusive by creating an empty iframe

Comment: @JuanMendes - Took me a while to think of this!

Comment: @Derek wow, that actually does it. Good job. Now to figure out how to get rid of the flash.

Comment: That is actually tricky across browsers, the easiest way is to give you iframe a name, and window.frames.frameName is a reference to the `Window` object.

Comment: @JuanMendes That is not a good practice. `window.frames` is just an alias for `window` itself (`window === window.frames`). The expression `window.frames.frameName` is equivalent to `window.frameName`. Here, `frameName` is an implicit global variable (created automatically by the browser). However, if a global variable with that name already exists or if such a global variable is created subsequently by a JavaScript program, the reference will break. Such implicit global variables are not reliable, and should be avoided.

Comment: @Derek you and ŠimeVidas both deserve an accept, but I'm going to go with his because he was the first to write the solution I'm going with, and because his code doesn't leave leftover variables etc.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to not lose it if someone overwrites it is for you to keep your own reference before someone overwrites it.

Therefore, before you include any other scripts, include the following script

```
var hasOwnProp = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
```

and use `hasOwnProp` everywhere else.

Comment: Right, that's the only solution I could find too. The problem is that now you're mandating the order of the scripts on the page, and if you can do that then this isn't a problem anyway.

Comment: you're only mandating the order of one line of script, not the whole order of scripts

Comment: Yes, I don't mean to say this isn't an improvement. Just that the question is more directed at whether there's a way to recover if the problem script is run before any of your code, which we'd have to assume is the case if we're writing for something like a library which is used in environments we don't control.

Answer (score 0):

To me, that's a non-question. You state on your post and comments that:

- It's hypothetical
- It's based on the fact that "someone" can modify your script, and there's nothing you can do about it.
- You are not happy with any solution that involves controlling the scripts loading order.

Why not? Aren't you the developer? And if "someone" does modify `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`, the solution is quite simple: remove the offending script from your page! It's not like someone broke into your code and did that, it's you who linked to someone's poorly-written script.

PS: I'm sorry if this isn't an actual answer to your question, but it's too long for a comment.

Comment: My words were "mostly theoretical", which means that I don't expect it to come up more than very rarely. But very rarely is the difference between good code and bulletproof code. And most large-scale production environments contain code written by multiple people, some by third parties like advertises. So, yes, it's true that I don't control every script on the page.

Comment: Theoretical questions or hypothetical questions are questions, too.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - [`You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.`](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: @Derek I would say that this problem is both answerable, as we already have an answer, and based on an actual problem, as there are a huge number of scenarios where a developer cannot be guaranteed that this situation will not arise.

Comment: @Derek Heh, I didn't know that :). I've been violating that rule a lot, since I regularly ask theoretical JavaScript-related questions.

Comment: @st-boost Don't get me wrong, I learnt from Šime Vidas' answer too. But I still think this is not a real issue. You may not be able to control third-party code, but you can control the order it's added to your code. As for someone on your own team screwing up, well, it's more a team-management problem than a code problem. What if you're writing C++ code and someone cluelessly overrides the `==` operator?

Comment: @bfavaretto You can't control the order if you're writing a library. But I do agree that, if there's a more practical solution like educating team members or changing the code order, it would be preferable.

Comment: @Derek as I said to bfavaretto, it's not hypothetical if you're writing a library. I guess that's my fault for not making it clear, but that's why I was asking it.